# how to write mocha test that have timeout and async both

Tags: mocha.js

createStream need to get permission of browser's video&audio，so i have to delay this test

both `createStream` and `destroyStream` return promise

i want to test destroyStream, this just not get what i want, anyone Help?

```js
it("my test need to be delayed, and i want to test destroyStream", function () {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    // i need to create stream first
    const publishStream = await createStream();
    expect(streamCenter.previewVideoList.length).to.equal(1);

    // then destory stream
    await zg.destroyStream(publishStream);
    expect(streamCenter.previewVideoList.length).to.equal(0);
  }, 2000); // my test need to be delayed
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
it("my test need to be delayed, and i want to test destroyStream", async function () {
    this.timeout(10000); // set timeout 10s
    // i need to create stream first
    const publishStream = await createStream();
    expect(streamCenter.previewVideoList.length).to.equal(1);

    // then destory stream
    await zg.destroyStream(publishStream);
    expect(streamCenter.previewVideoList.length).to.equal(0);
  
});
```

this seems work if i allow the permission in time。 otherwise it will failed with Error 'Permission denied'